# Is there a fix for the jaxb2-maven-plugin:schemagen to work with JDK8?

Tags: java, maven, java-8, maven-jaxb2-plugin

In JDK 7 jaxb2-maven-plugin produces a warning about apt being removed, it now has in JDK8 and I can not sure how to get the plugin to work with JDK8.

> warning: The apt tool and its associated API are planned to be removed
>   in the next major JDK release.  These features have been superseded by
>   javac and the standardized annotation processing API,
>   javax.annotation.processing and javax.lang.model.  Users are
>   recommended to migrate to the annotation processing features of javac;
>   see the javac man page for more information.

I have created a ticket on the project page: [MJAXB-83](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MJAXB-83).

Comment: Have you filed in the ticket on JIRA?. Link is on the web site of the plugin.

Comment: Am in the process of, however; I thought since the plugin has been emitting the error since JDK7 for quite some time there may be a solution.

Comment: [MJAXB-83](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MJAXB-83) for the issue ticket.

Comment: this warning is actually from `schemagen` executable and not from the `jaxb2-maven-plugin`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The JAXB2 schemagen works with JDK8 as of version 1.6, it's enough to update the plugin reference in the project's `pom.xml`.

Comment: Thanks, I should have updated from issue ticket [MJAXB-83](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MJAXB-83). Please check ticket for related information/caveats.